# Can't set "Use Secure URLs in Frontend"

Tags: admin, ssl, secure

In Magento 1.9.2.4, when I go to System > Configuration > Web > Secure and set `Use Secure URLs in Frontend` to Yes, when I click Save, the field is set back to No.

Before clicking save:
[image]

After clicking save:
[image]

My goal is to make the whole site use https. All Secure Base * URLs are set correctly:
[image]

There are no entries in the logs when this happens and there are no relevant script errors. I note that it says "Store View" next to the settings, however I've looked at the store views and website settings and they all say use the Default.

I also see the same problem with `Use Secure URLs in Admin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that no admin settings could be saved. I went into the Magento database and set

`core_config_data`.`web/secure/use_in_frontend` to 1
`core_config_data`.`web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` to 1

This allowed me to save settings in admin, however it didn't fix my SSL. I had to the use the Admin UI to set “Use Secure URLs in Frontend” to No and then set it back to Yes, without clicking save in between. Same for the Admin HTML setting.

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution here. Don't forget to accept your own answer 48 hours after adding so that your question is marked as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento config:set  web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 0

php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_frontend 0
```